# fullCalendar: validRange from now date with current time

Tags: date, vue.js, datetime, fullcalendar

I am using [Full Calendar Vue](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/vue). I want to set my `validRange` from my current time. Currently as per the [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange) i set it as a **prop** to my FullCalendar component this way.

`:validRange="nowDate => {return {start: nowDate}}"`

My calendar view is `defaultView="timeGridWeek"`.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You don't seem to have asked us a question or described a problem. What exactly is it that you are thanking us for?

Comment: @ADyson I want the validRange set from my current time. So, what's happening now is if my time 4:00PM then i still able to select my 2:00PM slot. which is not valid.

Comment: as far as I can tell validRange only works for dates, not times. You might need to combine with selectAllow

Comment: i did it via `dateClick` and checking `if(arg.date > new Date()){ // add event }`